# How can I test validation annotations?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa

How can I test annotation based validation? I know that it only works with things that know how to recognize the annotations, and it seems that by default the test frameworks (JUnit, TestNG) do not recognize these.

```
public class Foo {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 110)
    private String description;

    public method describe ( String desc ) {
       this.description = desc;
    }
}
```

*update*: For example how would I go about ensuring that when I attempt to set the description, that it will throw an error (if used by things that recognize the annotations)  if I do `Foo.new.describe( ' ' )` or `Foo.new.describe( null )`.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you're trying to do; it's not clear. If you're asking about testing a validator, then the existing validator libraries have extensive test suites already. If you're asking about making sure that your configuration has one wired up correctly, you need to load a test context, pass in an invalid object, and make sure you get the appropriate application error.

Comment: @chrylis sorry, updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is kinda confusing. I'll try to answer two different aspects of the question.

> How can I test validation annotations?

If those validation Annotations conforms to [Java JSR-303 Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org) (which seems to be this case), you can validate those objects and make the desired assertions on Unit Tests using [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator) or another implementation.

**Example:**

```
public class FooTest {

   private static Validator validator;

   @BeforeClass
   public static void setUp() {
      ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
      validator = factory.getValidator();
   }

   @Test
   public void checkIfIsNull() {
      Foo foo = new Foo(); // Field is null at this point

      Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(foo);

      assertTrue(constraintViolations.size() > 0);
   }
}
```

--

> For example how would I go about ensuring that when I attempt to set the description, that it will throw an error (if used by things that recognize the annotations) if I do Foo.new.describe(' ') or Foo.new.describe(null)

You're talking about runtime validation here, not Unit Testing. You can check and throw the recommended exception this way:

```
public void describe(String desc) {
    if (desc == null || desc.trim().isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("[desc] parameter is null or empty");

    ...
}
```

PS: Here I'm assuming that the `describe(String)` method is not actually `setDescription(String)`.

Comment: `describe` is `setDescription` sorry (using DDD and I think `describe` is a natural way of "setting the description"). I'm apparently doing a really bad job of making questions today. But not asking about how to validate within the method (or test exceptions thrown from the method), which is a separate concern, though I think leaving it in the answer is good ;). This was all about seeing that the bean validation is actually doing its job properly. Which you seem to have answered in the first part.

Comment: Ok then, I guess you'll be good on validating your objects with Hibernate Annotations on your Unit Tests :) Do you need anything else?

Comment: nope, I'll probably accept the answer later, I tend to wait on accepting answers so people can get votes.

Comment: Oh, so nice of you! :)